# Android: How to run application forever in background?

Tags: android, android-intent

i have created an app which send user location to server..and it runs in background using async task(doInBackground and onPostExecute method)...but it runs very slow..in coding i have used Thread.sleep(300000) for interval of 5 minutes...i think the application stop running..

YasarKhan.java

```
    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1000; // 1000
                                                                        // meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 20; // 20 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    boolean done = true;

//  public YasarKhan(Context context) {
//      this.mContext = context;
//      
//
//  }



    public void gpsTraking() {

        // check if GPS enabled
        if (true) {
            stAdd = "";
            double latitude = getLatitude();
            double longitude = getLongitude();
            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
            try
            {
                List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 2);
                Address a = list.get(0);
                for (int i = 0; i <= a.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    stAdd = stAdd + "\n " + a.getAddressLine(i);
                }
                stAdd = stAdd + " " + a.getLocality() + "\n"
                        + a.getFeatureName();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }

    public void passing() 
    {
        new SendFeedback().execute(imei,simSerialNumber,stAdd,currentTime);
    }


    class SendFeedback extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... paramArrayOfParams) 
        {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("strIMEINumber", paramArrayOfParams[0]);
            request.addProperty("strSIMNumber", paramArrayOfParams[1]);     
            request.addProperty("strAddress", paramArrayOfParams[2]);
            request.addProperty("strTime", paramArrayOfParams[3]);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

            try 
            {
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                // SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                String resultData = response.toString();
                Log.d("response", resultData);
                return resultData;              
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.d("My Error", "" + e.getMessage());

            }
            return resultData;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            Log.d("strResult", result);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

MyReceiver.java

```
package com.example.yasar;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


         public static final String TAG = "com.example.gpstraking";
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
         {

             try
             { 

                 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, YasarKhan.class);
                context.startService(serviceIntent);     
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 Log.e("My Service Error",e.getMessage());
             }


        }



}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.yasar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("naveeeen","kushwaaahaACTIVITY");
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, YasarKhan.class);
        this.startService(serviceIntent);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess the DVM here may not be responsible for the termination of these asnyc tasks, if it's device you are testing on, make sure there are no 3rd party application (task killers) installed as they usually run a cycle of clean ups every now n then.. and instead try using wait notify than a forever while loop with sleep

Comment: Thread.sleep(300000); using this will generate inaccurate sleep/delay

Comment: stack_ved: how do i use wait instead sleep and while method....and i will check about clean up

Comment: @YasarKhan try SystemClock.sleep for making the code wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use service , in onStartCommand() :

1. **Use requestLocationUpdates.**

   ```
   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 0, myLocationListener);
   ```
2. **Call this method to check providers in onStartCommand()**

   ```
    public void testProviders() 
       { 
           //Choose only one provider                    
           Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);      
           if (location != null)
           {
               lat = location.getLatitude();
               lng = location.getLongitude();
               str = "Test Provider method says :"+" Latitude = " +lat + " and " + " Longitude = " +lng;
               System.err.println("Current Latitude and Longitude:"+lat+","+lng);

           }                
           else
           {
               str = " No Location ";
           }
           System.err.println(str);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   ```
3. **Use listener**

   ```
    LocationListener myLocationListener = new LocationListener()
       {

           @Override
           public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
           {
               if (location != null)
               {
                   Clat = location.getLatitude();
                   Clng = location.getLongitude();          
                   System.out.println("Change latitude and Longitude:"+Clat+", "+Clng+"timer: " +System.currentTimeMillis());                        
                   String str = " LocationListener : Change latitude and Longitude: " +Clat+ ", " +Clng+ "  timer: "  +System.currentTimeMillis();
                   System.err.println(str);
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   new SendPGLocationToServer().execute();
               }
               else
               {
                   str = " No Location. ";
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
   ```
4. **And at last, use AsyncTask to send location to server.**

Comment: Manish: i have almost done the samething...in logcat: ANR is not responding..SSL exception...no trusted certificates found